# Vue computed methods can't change data using setter in template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, get, set

I need change data using computed:

```
<template>
    <div>{{ userDataTest }}</div>
</template>

props: {
    exampleData: {
        type: Object,
        required: true,
    },
},

computed: {
    userDataTest: {
        get: function() {
            return this.exampleData;
        },
        set: function(newValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
            return newValue;
        },
    },
}

mounted () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Change now to null!');
        this.userDataTest = null;
    }, 5000);
},
```

I get data using props, next I create computed methods with getter and setter. I added `userDataTest` in `<template>`. And the I change (using `mounted`) data in `this.userDataTest` to null using setter. 
In `console.log(newValue);` in setter I see `newValue` is `null`, but in `<template>` nothing change still I have data from getter.

Why setter not change data in `<template>` to `null` ?

Comment: Your setter isn't doing anything but returning the input value. That alone won't have any effect.

Comment: The `this.userDataTest` always refer to the value returned from get method, which is exact the value of `this.exampleData`.

Comment: u can't mutate a prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Mutating a prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Prop-Mutation-deprecated) locally is considered an anti-pattern

However, you can use the [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) as shown below, but you can't set the prop to `null` because you are specifying that it has to be an `Object` type.

```js
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `<div>{{ userDataTest }}</div>`,
  props: {
    exampleData: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },

  computed: {
    userDataTest: {
      get: function() {
        return this.exampleData
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.$emit('update:exampleData', newValue)
      }
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Change now!')
      this.userDataTest = {}
    }, 2500)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      exampleData: {
        foo: 'bar'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-component :example-data.sync="exampleData"></my-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're trying to set the computed property's value by returning a new value, but Vue doesn't actually check the setter's return value. Perhaps you were trying to proxy a `data` variable through a computed property. If so, the setter should set that `data` variable in the setter body.

For instance, your component could declare a [`data` variable](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Data), named `userData`, which always has the latest value of the `exampleData` prop through a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers):

```js
export default {
  props: {
    exampleData: Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      userData: {}
    }
  },
  watch: {
    exampleData(exampleData) {
      this.userData = exampleData
    }
  },
}
```

Then, your template and computed prop would use `userData` instead:

```html
<template>
  <div>{{ userData }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  //...
  computed: {
    userDataTest: {
      get() {
        return this.userData
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.userData = newValue
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Edit Setting data through computed prop]